# In Bubble, how to resize image to fit in image element?

Tags: bubble.io

which one is the answer?
1 use shape element

2 processed with Imgix and then check "resize to fit the dimensions by cropping". And the last setting is run-mode rendering to "Stretch"

3 processed with Imgix and then check "Auto enhance the image". And the last setting is run-mode rendering to "Rescale"

4 processed with Imgix and then check "Applies an overall monochromatic hue change". And the last setting is run-mode rendering to "Stretch"

5 will try to make a better design

please tell me what is the answer. Thanks!